# rails postgres zsh Symbol not found: _rb_eEncCompatError (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, zsh, iterm

I have been troubleshooting a very odd issue in my local development rails setup for some time now.  While I can not track exactly when it started I wanted to post this to see if anyone else has seen this issue or has ideas on how to fix it.

How to duplicate this error. I startup iterm2 (zsh) and in the first tab in my project I run `rails s` to start the server.  As most developers do, I hit cmd+t to open a new tab and when I attempt to run `rails c` the rails console this error displays.  It's like I am restricted to a single tab.  I have found little research or direction online as to where to go with this issue and I am hoping someone out there could point me in the right direction.

It appears to be failing on the PG gem and I already verified I am running the latest version.

My .zshrc file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
export PATH=/Users/chrishough:/Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin:/Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/bin:/Users/chrishough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin:/Users/chrishoug$
```

Here is a copy of the  exact error that pops up in terminal.

```
/Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@My-Application-Profiles/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle: dlopen(/Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@My-Application-Profiles/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _rb_eEncCompatError (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@My-Application-Profiles/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@My-Application-Profiles/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle - /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@My-Application-Profiles/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
    from /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@My-Application-Profiles/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg.rb:4
    from /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /Users/chrishough/Huedio/Code/Profiles/config/application.rb:13
    from /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@My-Application-Profiles/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@My-Application-Profiles/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:39
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Thank you so much for your help everyone.  Have a great weekend.

***UPDATE***

From @crazymykl I updated my .zshrc config to look like this and the error appears to have gone away.

```
# RUBY DEVELOPMENT
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
# export PATH=/Users/chrishough:/Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin:/Users/chrishough/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/bin:/Users/chrishough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin:/Users/chrishoug$
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your issue is that your .zshrc refers to `ruby-1.9.3-head`, and it's looking at `ruby-1.9.3-p374` to find the pg_ext.bundle. Mismatched versions cause all sorts of oddness.

Comment: I just posted an update, is that what you were referring to? I want to confirm before I close this out.  Thank you so much.